# domaincheck(TLD) what is available via PHP API

Tags: php, api

I'm building an domaincheck and it's working now. If i test for example example.com it says example.com is available of is **not** available.

But if it is not available i want my code to check the other ones (like example.org, example.nl, example.net, example.info etc.) to see if those are available or not.

**This is my checker code**

```
unset($command);
$command = array(
"command" => "DomainsCheckAvailability",
"domain" => htmlentities($_POST['domain']),
"tld" => htmlentities($_POST['tld'])
);

$api = new Versio_api();
$versio = $api->api_send( $command );

IF($versio['success']==0) {
            echo("Fout opgetreden. Fout code: ".$versio['command_response_code'].". Fout text: ".$versio['command_response_message']."");
        }
        else
        {
            IF($versio['status']==1) {
                echo "<div class='wrapper'>";
                    echo "<div class='beschikbaar'>";
                        echo $_POST['domain'].$_POST['tld']. "";
                        echo " is available.";
                    echo "</div'>";
                echo "</div'>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<div class='wrapper'>";
                    echo "<div class='beschikbaar'>";
                        echo $_POST['domain'].$_POST['tld']. "";
                        echo " is not available.";
                    echo "</div'>";
                echo "</div'>";
            };
        };
```

**And these are my input fields:**

```
<form action="domeincheck.php" method="post">
            <input class="www" type="text" value="www." /></input>
            <input class="invul" placeholder="uw websitenaam" type="text" name="domain"></input>
                <select id="dropdownveld" name="tld">
                    <option value=".nl">.nl</option>
                    <option value=".com">.com</option>
                    <option value=".net">.net</option>
                    <option value=".be">.be</option>
                    <option value=".eu">.eu</option>
                    <option value=".org">.org</option>
                    <option value=".biz">.biz</option>
                    <option value=".info">.info</option>
                </select>
            <button class="btn_submit" type="submit" name="SubMit" class="input">Controleren</button>
         </form>
```

Hope you can help!

Comment: Where is the $versio variable coming from?

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: i'm sorry added the versio variable. @Epodax

Comment: The problem is i'm not getting the output because i need to find a way but tried the wrong ways i think. @Jean

Comment: Looking at what I guess to be the documentation here: http://www.versio.nl/api-doc/pages/DomainsCheckAvailability.html the tld you pass in shouldn't include the dot, but your html select code includes the dot in each of the option values, that's probably causing some problems (unless the API deals with that automatically).

Comment: just added the dot so the output says example.com and not examplecom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you have a function that performs the check? I'll assume that's called `domainAvailable()`. All you need to do is create an array of the TLDs you want to check, then loop over them, adding to the end of the domain name you're checking, and check each one:

```
function domainAvailable($domain, $tld) {
    $command = array(
            "command" => "DomainsCheckAvailability",
            "domain" => $domain,
            "tld" => $tld
    );

    if ( $tld[0] == '.') {
        $tld = substr($tld, 1);
    }

    $api = new Versio_api();
    $res = $api->api_send( $command );

    if ( $res['success'] )
        return $res['status'] == 1;

    return false;
}

$first_tld = $_POST['tld'];
$domain = $_POST['domain'];

if ( !domainAvailable($domain, $first_tld) ) {
    echo '<br/>Domain '.htmlentities($domain.'.'.$first_tld).' is not available.<br/>What about these?<br/>';
    $tlds = array('nl', 'com', 'net', 'be', 'eu', 'org', 'biz', 'info');
    foreach($tlds as $tld) {
        # Skip the first tld that was checked
        if ( $tld != $first_tld) {
            if ( domainAvailable($domain, $tld) )
                echo '<br>'.htmlentities($domain).$tld.' is available';
            else
                echo '<br>'.htmlentities($domain).$tld.' is not available';
        }
    }
}
else {
    echo '<br/>Domain '.htmlentities($domain.'.'.$first_tld).' is available';
}
```

*Update:* I've created a `domainAvailable()` function based on your updated code example.

*Update 2:* I've changed the code a bit. It should work provided you can get the `domainAvailable()` function correct, I've made a best guess on it based on the API docs, and the code you've posted.

Comment: checkdomain is not my function and if i change it it still isn't working the text stays black

Comment: i tried; if ($available['success']==1) but then it says everything is not available

Comment: I've updated the code a bit to include a function for doing the checking.

Comment: it is still not working. The first check isn't working anymore and the other checks al giving not available.

Comment: I'm only providing example code, I can't be sure that it works 100%, because I don't have the api class you're using for the checks. What domain are you actually checking?

Comment: Just random domains like asdasdasd.com so i know for sure it is available but than it's giving not available

Comment: asdasdasd.com is a registered domain name.

Comment: oh lol just typed something here. also check testeeneindop.com and it says its not available

Comment: I've updated the code again. And this time I've had a chance to run and test it too, so it should work for you, provided you can get the `domainAvailable()` function correct, I don't have access to the API so I can't really test that. I used a version of that function that just randomly returned true or false, and the code works fine with that.

Answer (score 0):

You set the TLD in this piece of code:

```
$command = array(
[...]
"tld" => htmlentities($_POST['tld'])
);
```

In this case it comes from the $_POST. If you create an array which contains all TLD's you want to check, create a loop in which you put them as the "tld" in $command and perform

```
$api->api_send( $command );
```

You will get the response for each TLD.

Comment: Don't know exactly what you are meaning

Comment: The request you are sending to Versio's api consists of 3 elements: Command, Domain and TLD. In this, TLD is the ".nl" part. So to get the availability of domains with another TLD you could put the ones you want to check in a list. Then for each item in this list execute the request to Versio.

Comment: I cant comment on Vex's answer but you could try adding the '.' to each item in the array $tlds he created because in your initial html code the values all have the dot in them and those are sent and used via $_POST.